# QTP not recording webtables in IE 11

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have one sample webtable created in VB script in  IE11. Have mentioned code below.

When I try recording in QTP & click on any element on webtable in IE 11 browser, QTP doesnt record any script.

```
<h2>Employment Application</h2>
<form name="frmEmployees">
  <table border="0" width="320">
    <tr>
      <td width="80">First Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtFirstName" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="80">Last Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtLastName" size="10">
        <input type="button" value="Evaluate" name="btnEvaluate"
    onClick="form.txtFullName.value = form.txtLastName.value + ', ' + 
                      form.txtFirstName.value">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="80">Full Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtFullName" size="24"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> <input type = "reset" name = "RstButton" > </td>
   </tr>

    </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Since you mentioned QTP, I assume that you're using QTP11. If so, be informed that it won't support the later versions of IE8 according to its PAM. So may be you can try for latest UFT version which would support IE7 - IE11.

Answer (score 0):

According to Trudy Claspill on the [HP Supportforums](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Does-QTP-11-supports-IE-11-Do-We-have-any-Patches-for-QTP-11-to/m-p/6688894) QTP is not supporting IE11. The first version which is supporting it is UFT12.

> According to that, IE 11 is not supported for QTP 11.0.
>
> The first version to support IE 11 on Windows 8  is UFT 12. The first version to support IE 11 on Windows 7 SP1 is also UFT 12.

But even UFT12 seems to have several problems with IE11 as there are several threads asking for patches for several functions.

Another post from an HP Expert ([Source](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Latest-versions-supported-by-UFT-12/m-p/6416832#M6887)) contains the missing support for IE11 for QFT11.53 in detail:

> For the lates version availabel which is UFT 11.53 are:
>
> Internet Explorer 10.
>
> Firefox 24.
>
> Chrome 30.

So if you want to test in IE11 you need to upgrade to UFT12.